# Always use Xen?

Tags: virtualization, xen

I'm installing the usual bunch of servers for general office stuff, a mixture of Windows/Sharepoint and Linux

Since none of these need direct access to the hardware, fancy graphics or are really performance-critical it makes sense to run them virtualised so I can easily back them up, move them to new HW.

Xen uses essentially no CPU or memory and has no limitations on the guest OS (with VT-x) doesn't it make sense to always have it there even if you are currently only running a single guest?

Answer (score 1):

For situations like you're describing, generally yes. It makes sense these days to install Xen, ESX, Hyper-V, or whatever your flavor of popular Virtualization software may be. As you pointed out the drawbacks are miniscule, and the potential benefits can be staggering in the right circumstances.